# Mocking a nested method when the parent method needs to be executed in a new process

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I need to write a unit test where I want to run the method under test in a new process I create using multiprocessing (as later I want to send a exit signal to this process and test if the program exits successfully). This method has a nested method call to another method that I would like to mock it's behavior. But seems like, the states of the mocked method is not shared across different processes. Is there any way/tool I can use to achieve this?

Let's say the method I want to test is as follows:

```
def method_to_test():
     signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, partial(signal_handler))
     result = nested_method()
     while True: 
       do_something()
```

In the test I have:

```
@patch(nested_method, side_effect = ...)
def test_method_to_test():
   process = multiprocessing.Process(target=main)
   process.start()
   time.sleep(3)
   process.terminate()
   process.join()
   assert process.exitcode == 0
```

Seems the side_effect I am defining here is not really executed and the real nested_method is executed actually.

Comment: It's a new process with a new memory space. It doesn't know anything about your mocks.